# Build UWP application source code on Windows 7 with VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-7, uwp

I got the following message when project opened:

[image: Error Message]

Is it possible to build UWP application on Windows 7?

Comment: From [Develop apps for the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx): *"Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 support - If you choose to develop Universal Windows apps with Visual Studio 2015 on a platform other than Windows 10, these are the restrictions: Windows 7: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can’t use the emulators or the simulator in Visual Studio either."* - Should be possible to build UWP applications on Windows 7, you just cannot run/debug them.

Comment: I read that. But I cannot compile it. VS2015 even cannot open corresponding project. When I try to "Install Missing Features" I get message the same as on screenshot. So from docs - I can do that.. really - I cannot... so just trying to ask somebody to be sure.

Comment: You aren't trying to build the solution, though. You are trying to open it in Visual Studio. Try to build it from the command line instead.

Comment: Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v12.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file
exists on disk. And I do not think that I should not be able to build project from VS. I understand that I cannot run.. but open project and build should be available if MS claims like you wrote....

Comment: This appears to be a C# solution, looking for a .targets file for Visual Studio **2013** (v12.0). Is this intentional?

Comment: It is from sln file... This sln distributed as library source code. I have only VS2015 installed.. Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.40629.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1

Comment: Either install the Visual Studio release the library code expects, or migrate the solution file. The latter is probably a manual process, and you'll have to know what you're doing.

Comment: OK, I will try to convert.. what can be the reason for that? Why other projects are successfully compiled without VS2013 and UWP project cannot be build? Do you really think it can be a reason?

Comment: The error message you received on the command line is pretty unambiguously clear. The solution is looking for standard project files that ship with Visual Studio 2013. The reason: The author of the library probably used Visual Studio 2013 to create the solution. If other (UWP) solutions compile fine, it would be interesting to compare the .sln files with those that don't. They probably reference files that are part of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: VS2015 can open sln and all projects in sln. But it cannot open this specific UWP project. And projects are compiled fine from this sln except UWP project. I guess VS is backward compatible with 2013 sln file.

Comment: The error message from the command line clearly indicates, that the solution is referencing a project that is installed with Visual Studio 2013. So either install Visual Studio 2013 to compile this project, or update the solution/project file(s) to be compatible with Visual Studio 2015. Or ask the author/vendor of the library to provide a solution that is compatible with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I think it is my mistake. And this project type is not UWP. So let's think it is solved.